# Cause of dropping packet in wireless network simulation in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

In my omnet++ simulation, I have a wireless network. When the simulation is run, the NOT_ADDRESSED_TO_US error will occurred. What is the reason of it? How solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireless communication is inherently broadcasting to all receivers in the range so a lot of receiver will get a message that is not addressed to them (i.e. the destination address does not match any of its own mac address). This is normal, it's not an error by any means.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to obtain overall throughput, end-to-end delay, packet drop sum in Omnet++ in a wifi wireless network including some nodes. The causes of packet loss(drops)  due to errors are considered not as NOT_ADDRESSESED_TO_US error. .Please would you mind helping me?
Thanks a lot.